# RangeError: index out of range error

Tags: java

I run Noble on the Raspberry Pi 3 (with Bluetooth) and i receive RSSI values from the nearby beacons that i have. However, if noble is ran the whole times i occasionally get the following error. Please help solve this issue.

`/home/pi/node_modules/noble/lib/hci-socket/hci.js:526
debug('\t\tdata len = ' + len);
^
RangeError: index out of range
at checkOffset (buffer.js:619:11)
at Buffer.readInt8 (buffer.js:745:5)
at Hci.processLeAdvertisingReport (/home/pi/node_modules/noble/lib/hci-socket/hci.js:643:21)
at Hci.processLeMetaEvent (/home/pi/node_modules/noble/lib/hci-socket/hci.js:608:10)
at Hci.onSocketData (/home/pi/node_modules/noble/lib/hci-socket/hci.js:479:12)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at BluetoothHciSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $`

Comment: Looks like a bug in that package. Report it on the issue tracker.